# Other approaches to $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K\left ( x \right ) }{\sqrt{3-x} } \text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, elliptic-integrals

Let $K(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2 \sin^2 \theta}}d\theta$ be the complete elliptic integral of first kind. It could be shown that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K\left ( x \right ) }{\sqrt{3-x} } \text{d}x=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{24}  \right ) 
\Gamma\left ( \frac{5}{24}  \right)\Gamma\left ( \frac{7}{24}  \right ) \Gamma\left (  \frac{11}{24}\right )  }{96\pi\sqrt{3}}
$$
thanks to [the known results here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616312/).
With its simple appearance, I wonder whether   a brief approach exists so that we can understand them better. Appreciate your creative efforts.

---

Applying the well-known quadratic transformation formula
$$
K\left ( \frac{1-x}{1+x}  \right ) 
=\frac{1+x}{2} K^\prime(x),K^\prime(x):=K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^2}  \right )
$$
we get
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(x)}{\sqrt{3-x} }\text{d}x
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } \int_{0}^{1} \frac{K^\prime(x)}{\sqrt{\left ( 1+x\right )\left ( 1+2x \right )  } }
\text{d} x.
$$
If using the expansion
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left ( 1+x\right )\left ( 1+2x \right )  } }
=\sum_{n\ge0} a_n x^n
$$
and $$ \int_{0}^{1}x^n K^\prime(x)\text{d}x
=\frac\pi4\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{n+1}{2}  \right )^2 }{
\Gamma\left ( \frac{n+2}{2}  \right )^2},$$
we could obtain a series representation for the integral. This works more on the case mentioned by @MiracleInvoker, because the series could split into two hypergeometric series, both of which are normally evaluated.

Comment: How about the simpler case,
$$\int_0^1\frac{K}{\sqrt{1-k}}dk=\frac{\Gamma^2(1/8)\Gamma^2(3/8)}{2^{9/2}\pi}$$

Comment: I'm unsure how helpful this is for what you are asking, but maybe someone else can make some headway with it... $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K(x)}{\sqrt{b-x}}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4b}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}+n\big)}{n!}\bigg)^2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1/b)^m}{m!(2n+m+1)\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}-m\big)}$$